# I am trying to add in a pivot filter field but I don't know what is wrong with my code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a filter on my pivot table and I don't know why it not reading my code right.

It is saying "Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField Class"

```
Sub Filter_MasterCode()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim sField As String

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    sField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

    For Each pf In pt.PageFields
        If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
            pf.Orientation = xlHidden
        End If
    Next pf

    For Each pf In pt.DataFields
        If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
            pf.Orientation = xlHidden
        End If
    Next pf

    pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlPageField

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(sField)
      .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
      .PivotItems("1").Visible = True
    End With

    Select Case sField
        Case Is = "Apple"
          With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("2017")
              .Orientation = xlDataField
          End With
    End Select
```

It say error at `.PivotItems("0").Visible = False`

Thank you

Comment: Could you add a sample of your pivot table? I would guess that `.PivotItems("0")` is not a valid reference. If you are trying to do it based on the first item then the index starts at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you are attempting to get the first [PivotItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotitem) within the collection.

The index for a `PivotItem` Object starts at `1`. You are attempting to access the `0` index. Change that and see if that works.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(sField)
  .PivotItems(1).Visible = False
  .PivotItems(2).Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Also note, since it is it's index I would also have it as a number vs a string. I did that in my example but forgot to mention it. Cheers!